# Show $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$ is a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Unfortunately, $(x^2)$ is not a prime ideal, so I can't use the trick of "quotient of a PID by a prime ideal is a field". However, I do know that $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is itself a PID, and the Lattice Isomorphism Theorem says that ideals of $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$ correspond to ideals of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ containing $(x^2)$ via the map $J\mapsto J+(x^2)$. Can I use this to show every ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$ is principal?

Comment: Is it even a domain? What about $x + (x^2) \in \Bbb R[x] / (x^2)$? Isn't it a divisor of zero?

Comment: Note that for any ring $R$ with identity and for any ideal $I$ of the corresponding polynomial ring $R[x],$ the quotient ring $R[x]/I$ is a domain iff $I$ is a prime ideal of $R[x].$

Comment: It seems like you're mostly asking if every ideal in the quotient is principal. Since $J$ is principal, $J+(x^2)$ is principal, as it is generated by the image of the generator of $J$. That is, if $J=(f)$, then $J+(x^2)=(f+(x^2))$. The quotient is only a principal ideal ring, not a domain.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.